# Updating a document with mongoDB and mongoHQ

Tags: json, mongodb, updates, mongohq

I'm a little confused as far as updating a document in mongo is concerned.  I'm using API calls with mongoHQ to do so.  Say I have the following document:

```
{
  _id: "1234"
}
```

If I use the API call mentioned [here](http://docs.mongohq.com/mongohq-api/documents.html), I **am able** to successfully update the document with the following PUT body:

```
{
    "document": {
        "$set": {
            "statistics": {
                "http://localhost:8888/": "base"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the resulting document is:

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  statistics: {
    "http://localhost:8888/": "base"
  }
}
```

But if I try doing something like this:

```
{
    "document": {
        "$set": {
            "statistics": {
                "http://localhost:8888/": "base",
                "http://localhost:8888/robots.txt": "robots"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It refuses to update.  Am I missing a key aspect of document updating with mongodb??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names cannot contain a period (`.`). In the second example, the second URL contains a period ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions%20on%20Field%20Names)): `robots.txt`.

You'll need to encode the character before updates. (like a %2E for example).

Comment: Fantastic!  I knew I had to be missing something!